# PrimeNg Calendar Module: Input box shown very small

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using Angular2, primeng 2.0.4.

I followed all the steps as mentioned on website "https://www.primefaces.org/primeng". Now on using the below code:

```
<form class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <p-calendar [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <p-calendar [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar>
</div>

</form>
```

The size of the input box shwon is very small. See image below:
[DateTime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anHdo.png)

Please help.

Comment: it is working perfectly fine. when I reproduced it

Comment: @David: I got a clue from your comment, that some stylesheet is causing. I can see if I remove one of the custom css being used in my project, then it works fine. Checking now which property is being overrideen. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clue from David helped, the issue was the with stylesheet selector classes. The style selector class names from primeng.css with conflicting with my other local css. Due to which correct styles were not taken. Thanks!!